# Connect Java Websocket endpoint to mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, websocket

We are building a websocket webapp for a school project and would like to store the incoming information to MySQL. Currently we are using netbeans and the Server Endpoint is written in Java. The info sent from the client side is a JSON obj. We can decode it but dont't know how to insert it into the table

Problems we are facing

1.We are used to programming Java application and using mysql JDBC but this time we cannot find the library to add, like we use to do.

2.We have tried AJAX but since the PHP is on a different server we cant do it, and I can't find the option to add a PHP file to the current project in netbeans. -- Currently I'm trying to learn how to do AJAX with JSP

3.We think we need to spin a thread so that the reply doesn't have to wait for the insert to complete but when we try to spin a thread the Endpoint no longer works, so we commented it out

4.We are trying to keep third party Frame works to a minimum

Below is the code to our Server Endpoint

```
 public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
    // Create JsonObject from message
    JsonObject jsonObject = new Message(message).getJObject();

    // Decode JsonObject
    message = Decoder(jsonObject);


    for (Session peer : peers) {
        try {
             if (!peer.equals(session)) { 

            peer.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
             }
         } catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(ServerEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }
}
```

This is our current decoder. We wanted to spin a thread from this function, I don't know if that is a good idea or not

```
public String Decoder(JsonObject jObject) {
    String message;
    message = jObject.getString("msg");

    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Netbeans use Glassfish, I downloaded the MySQL JDBC and put it in the lib folder as I would if I was running Tomcat. Then I go into the Admin console and added the JDBC Connector then added the JDBC Resource. Next restart the server then redeploy the app.